# Add Custom Snap-Lines to UIView for Interface Builder

Tags: xcode, uiview

I have always wondered if there is a way to add custom "snap lines" to a UIView descendant, so I have a nice mechanism to layout my views using the Interface Builder of Xcode.

Here is my very basic UIView:

[image: UIView Custom Control]

This view serves as a container control for other UIViews. Is there a way to add these lines so Xcode draws the "blue snap" lines when moving a control inside this view?

I know that there are UILayoutGuides but these don't add the desired snap lines to the Interface Builder (Xcode 9.3).

Here is another screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of where I want the snap line to be.]

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for this would be creating a view with a height of 1 and the width of its superview. After that, views with the same superview will snap to it.

Some tips:

- Set a light background color for the view, so that it won't be distracting.
- Remove the view when it's no longer needed. If you want to keep it for later usage, just hide it.

Comment: When I am using the Interface Builder on this view, this would work. But when I add a UIView to another view and set its class to the class of the "assembled view", this no longer works. I have added another screenshot that hopefully explains this a little bit better.